# Problem in figure environment in article

Tags: graphics, floats, article

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{1.2.jpg}
\caption{d}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

By using the above code I am getting the following error..

> Unknown graphics extension: .2.jpg. \includegraphics{1.2.jpg}

How to fix that??

Comment: Don't use `.jpg`: `\includegraphics{1.2}`

Comment: @RomainPicot no, it'll still see `.2` as the extension

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes but it's not the same error `:-P` (ok I tried to give a bad explanation to my comment `;-)`)

Comment: yes you are right @RomainPicot now its working.. thank yur